# sbt-native-packager - How to use AshScriptPlugin with LauncherJarPlugin in the same project

Tags: sbt-native-packager

My use case is to get a Play Framework application running in alpine docker container.

I would prefer to use a launcher jar.

So my `build.sbt` looks something like this:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(
  PlayScala,
  JavaAppPackaging,
  LauncherJarPlugin,
  AshScriptPlugin,
  UniversalDeployPlugin
)

maintainer in Universal := "G. Richard Bellamy <rbellamy@terradatum.com>"

packageSummary in Universal := "some-server"

packageDescription := "The some-server microservice"

// Necessary because the PlayScala plugin uses sbt-native-packager, and defines the bashScriptExtraDefines in the
// expectation that the app will be using the JavaServerAppPackaging plugin with bash, and we need to use the
// JavaAppPackaging plugin with Ash
bashScriptExtraDefines := Nil
```

Which produces the following relevant start script stanza:

```
real_script_path="$(realpath "$0")"
app_home="$(realpath "$(dirname "$real_script_path")")"
lib_dir="$(realpath "${app_home}/../lib")"

app_mainclass="-jar" "$lib_dir/some-server.some-server-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-launcher.jar"

script_conf_file="${app_home}/../conf/application.ini"
app_classpath=""


# If a configuration file exist, read the contents to $opts
[ -f "$script_conf_file" ] && opts=$(loadConfigFile "$script_conf_file")

java -classpath $app_classpath $opts $app_mainclass $@
```

Note the `app_classpath=""` variable. Given that I'm using a launcher jar, I would expect that line to be omitted.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: You are the first to my knowledge using this combination. I'll try to reproduce this. However I would recommend only enabling `AshScriptPlugin`. All other plugins are already enabled.

Comment: I'm also not sure if setting the `bashScriptExtraDefines` causes the main app to be empty.